# I can download file using Google Chrome but not using cURL in php

Tags: php, curl

I have a code here in php,

```
set_time_limit(0);

$ch = curl_init();

$link  = "https://somelinks-uploads";
$token = "sometoken";

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => "{$link}",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 3600,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
    CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS     => false,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => [
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer {$token}",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ]
]);

$response  = curl_exec($ch);
$err       = curl_error($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
```

Which, if I run, will not successfully download the file. It will just stop base on the allowed timeout

```
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3600,
```

The same with using an application like Insomnia, an alternative to postman. But when I am using Google Chrome and pasted the same link, I can download the file, although I need to wait for around 15-20mins because it's a large file.

What's going on?

What the problem with PHP cURL?

Comment: Have you tried `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0`?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try and see what happend

Comment: It stop when time spent reach 0:01:40

Comment: It could be as easy as that the browser is running into the same problem, but keeps retrying. Curl by itself has a `--retry` option, which unfortunately is still not exposed within PHP. You might want to look into the `CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM` option.

Comment: So, what error do you get?